# PayPal how to get merchant ID after seller onboarding?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to do paypal merchant onboarding for my users. I use following code. As you can see i provided return_url and i expected to get from this url merchantId to save it to my database but after onboarding process i only see page with message to confirm my email [confirm email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03s07.png). After confirmation of email, i redirected to only dashboard sandbox account

```
const data = {
            'tracking_id': 'testenterprices123122',
            'partner_config_override': {
                'return_url': 'https://vtx.uk',
            },
            'operations': [
                {
                    'operation': 'API_INTEGRATION',
                    'api_integration_preference': {
                        'rest_api_integration': {
                            'integration_method': 'PAYPAL',
                            'integration_type': 'THIRD_PARTY',
                            'third_party_details': {
                                'features': [
                                    'PAYMENT',
                                    'REFUND'
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            'products': [
                'EXPRESS_CHECKOUT'
            ],
            'legal_consents': [
                {
                    'type': 'SHARE_DATA_CONSENT',
                    'granted': true
                }
            ]
        };

        const options = {
            url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
        };
  axios(options).then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I tried to use trackingId field to get after that my merchant information. I used following code but it gives me error RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND. And i tried to get webhooks, for example event after merchant onboard but it is not working, just no response

```
const options = {
             url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/partners/partner_id/merchant-integrations?tracking_id={tracking_id}',
             method: 'GET',
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
                 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
             },
         };
axios(options).then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Show referral data](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/#partner-referrals_read) GET API call, example from the documentation

> curl -v -X GET
> https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals/ZjcyODU4ZWYtYTA1OC00ODIwLTk2M2EtOTZkZWQ4NmQwYzI3RU12cE5xa0xMRmk1NWxFSVJIT1JlTFdSbElCbFU1Q3lhdGhESzVQcU9iRT0=
>
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
> -H "Authorization: Bearer "

Comment: but where i can get partner_refferal_id?

Comment: From the first API call in your question

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX thanks for attending all Paypal questions on SO. But this answer is not correct. Apparently, you can't get the Merchant ID with V2 API. If you do this get request you're suggesting, you'll only get the user info you provided on your first POST request. And the docs don't say merchant_id info is removed on V2. Instead, you get stuff like submitter_payer_id which is always useless. It's quite a frustrating experience to try to use V2 only, you have to go with v1 to get merchant_id.

Comment: The payer ID is the merchant ID.